# Error when creating a multi-factor user in Firebird 3 (RedDatabase)

Tags: firebird, red-database

An error occurs when trying to create a multi-factor user in RedDatabase.

When I try to create a new multifactor user using the command

```sql
create user "SYSDBA" password 'masterkey' using plugin multifactor_manager
```

I get the error

> Resource Exception. add record error; Unexpected call to
> Firebird::LongJump::stuffException() [SQLState:HY000, ISC error
> code:335544382].

Message in logs:

> Cryptographic operation is failed. Error: specified plugin not found

Settings were made to configure the plugin in firebird.conf. The error is repeated on several databases. Reinstalling Firebird does not help. Please help with solving this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure you'll get answer for RedDatabase here. The error suggests that one or more dependencies for this _"multifactor_manager"_ plugin are not available or not configured correctly. If the plugin itself was not available, you'd probably have received an error like _"Missing requested management plugin"_. I'd suggest contacting RedDatabase support.

Comment: RDB is a commercial project with its own support. This question should go there.

Comment: @user13964273 The fact Red Database has commercial support in no way means the question cannot be asked here on Stack Overflow. However, I think it is unlikely to get an answer here, so contacting Red Database support is probably the better approach to get support.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I will follow your advice